# Single word for a person who makes things difficult

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

I am in search of a word that exactly means 'a difficult person of my description'.

For example, suppose that I am on the lookout for a heart specialist, and I ask my friend if he is familiar with any. Instead of answering this specific question, he begins describing the heart, its function, who can do without it, plausible the danger of being treated by doctors who skipped treatment of the heart in their studies, and so on and so forth. I am lost in a maze, my head goes whirling, and I fail to recollect what I was after.

Search among your acquaintances and you will find many similar examples. What I want is to give them an appropriate name–— preferably a single word.

Comment: *Troublemaker*!

Comment: Some politicians interviewed on TV have that effect.

Comment: Contrarian? Obstructionist? Obfuscationist?